# Xbee Wi-fi configuration using XCTU and Mac

Tags: wifi, xbee

I'm currently trying to configure XBee Wi-fi:s following Spark Fun's great "Xbee Wi-fi Hookup Guide" tutorial. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/xbee-wifi-hookup-guide

Firstly, as a side note, I'm using a Mac and have the 6.0.1. version of the XCTU.

So, I'm currently stuck in the sections 6. and 7. for "selecting my network". I suppose this refers to the wi-fi that I'm using at home? When connecting to it (with the correct password) I get each time the following message: "Error connecting to access point > Timeout waiting to be connected to the selected access point". Do you know what this means?

Also, I don't know if this information is useful, but I can see my Xbee's network/name when scanning for networks with my Mac's "network preferences", yet it doesn't show up in XCTU's active scan.

Warm regards,
Emilia

Answer (score 1):

In fact I got and answer straight from Digi's kind Tech Support group, which solved the problem!

"One of the possible reason for this issue might be configuration mismatch between how your Access Point and your XBee is setup.

Note that these XBee S6B modules supports only WPA and WPA2 protocol in PSK mode. Enterprise level 802.1x encryption is not supported in these modules. Hence, make sure that your Access Point supports and work on PSK mode.

Second, these modules are by default configured to acquire IP address from AP using AP's DHCP pool. If your AP is not configured to allot IP address to module, then switch to "Static IP" mode using "MA" command and provide IP address to module manually.

The last point you mentioned is an expected behavior of module and nothing to worry about. Please try out above provided solutions with module setup up with default configuration. Let us know if you face any issue in its implementation."